# Usage of a random function and lists

Tags: python, list

Here is my code

```
N=str(input("Enter the catagory: "))
 Countries=["canada","albania","cuba"]

if N=="Countries":
    y=random.choice(Countries)
```

if I do something like this the code takes the elements in the countries but when I try to create a function by using it I fail. For example I have many catogories so I dont want to write if function like 10 times for every catagory.Hence I tried to write it like this

```
  N=str(input("Enter the catagory: "))
  Countries=["canada","albania","cuba"]

  def cata(N):
    y=random.choice(N)
    z=len(str(y))
    return (z,y)
```

but at this time when I type countries I only get **the letters of the countries** so the code refers to the word "countries" but the list name.And I need the elements of the countries list. I am not sure how to fix it

thanks.

Well after the function ends I need both y and z values.

Comment: It's unclear how you're using the `cata` function. We can't debug your code without a [mcve].

Comment: okay I edited the post

Comment: The code still doesn't call the `cata` function.

Comment: I didnt understand ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a number of categories, and you need a single function to return a random value from one of those list, depending on the name of the list that you send, I think your best way of doing this is through a dictionary with lists as value. Something like

```
dic = { 
   'countries' : ["A","B","C"] 
   'cities' : ["X","Y","Z"]
}
```

Now your function can take the name of the list as a parameter, and use it to look up in the dictionary to get the appropriate list, and return a random value from that

```
N = str(input("Enter the catagory: "))
def cata(n):
    y = random.choice(dic[n])

cata(N)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing a str (a piece of data) with variables and a piece of program code.

If user enters `'Countries'` to the input, the string `N` gets turned into a list `['C', 'o', 'u', ...]` inside `random.choice(N)`.

To "fix" your program, you can do it this way:

```
Countries = ["canada","albania","cuba"]
N = str(input("Enter the catagory: "))
y = random.choice(eval(N))
...
```

HOWEVER, it is strongly discouraged to apply `eval()` to a string that user input.  Most users can be expected to make mistakes at least some of the time, and a malicious user can abuse it to break your program or even your system.